# Unknown column error when trying to pair current row with next row in time-ordered table in SQL

Tags: sql

There is a table stockprice, which contains information about trades of one company's stock. It has two columns: timestamp and price. They represent the time when a trade happened and the price of the sale. The natural order of records in the table is random and is not sorted by timestamp.

You add another column (let's call it delta) where you intend to store the difference between the current transaction price and the price of the previous transaction time-wise.

Write a single SQL statement, which will calculate the price difference and fill the column delta with it in all rows.

I write the sql as below to run on mysql,and i can't move on, the following is the one i wrote till now to calculate the difference between the current transaction price and the price of the previous transaction time-wise, mysql give me the "Unknown column 'previous.price' in 'field list'" error since the first row's previous is nothing, can some expert have a idea to solve this?:

```
 SELECT
   `current`.timestamp,
   `current`.price,
   `current`.price - IFNULL(`previous`.price, 0) AS delta
   FROM
   stockprice       AS `current`
LEFT JOIN
   stockprice       AS `next`
      ON `next`.timestamp = (SELECT MIN(timestamp)
                               FROM stockprice
                              WHERE timestamp > `current`.timestamp)
My database like:
timestamp                 price
2011-10-27 00:00:00       12424
2011-10-24 00:00:00       15464
2011-10-25 00:00:00       543464
2011-10-23 00:00:00       58791
```

Comment: if this is homework, please add homework tag

Comment: Is there a unique constraint (primary key constraint) on the timestamp column?

Comment: Please write question titles which provide useful information about the question. We know it's about sql because you tagged it as such. We know it's a question because you posted a question. The current title _"Difficult sql again, need expert?"_ adds nothing.

Comment: Add your database schema, some sample data, sample result, then it will be more easy to help you.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: yes, primary keyon the timestamp column

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: my mistake, i edited it already, the problem is just like i need to add one more condition that for the first row don't ask for its previous, thanks

Comment: @Utku Yıldırım: database added.

Comment: @MattBall What would you propose he put for the title?

Answer (score 1):

Decide whether you are dealing with next or previous timestamps:

```
SELECT `current`.timestamp,
       `current`.price,
       `current`.price - IFNULL(`previous`.price, 0) AS delta
  FROM stockprice       AS `current`
  LEFT JOIN stockprice  AS `previous`
    ON `previous`.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp)
                                 FROM stockprice
                                WHERE timestamp < `current`.timestamp)
```

Or avoiding the use of backticks:

```
SELECT C.timestamp,
       C.price,
       C.price - IFNULL(P.price, 0) AS delta
  FROM stockprice       AS C
  LEFT JOIN stockprice  AS P
    ON P.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(S.timestamp)
                        FROM stockprice AS S
                       WHERE S.timestamp < C.timestamp)
```

Comment: the error solved, but seems the result return is not correct.

Comment: Did you try the version with '>' or '<'?  I mistyped the first time and then edited it.

Answer (score 0):

> "Unknown column 'previous.price' in 'field list'"

I don't see anything in this query that would cause that error.  Are you sure this is the whole query you are running?  This doesn't have anything to do with there not being a 'previous' record for the first record to join to.  It means there's not a table (or alias) called previous with a column called price.

Comment: the error solved, but the return result still not correct, check Jonathan Leffler's solution,